# If $f$ is twice differentiable in some neighbourhood of $0$, and $\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{\sin(3x)}{x^3}+\frac{f(x)}{x^2})=0$ , find the value of $f''(0)$.

Tags: limits, derivatives

I would have thought of finding $f(0)$ first, then finding $f'(0)$, then i might be able to find $f''(0)$.
So as usual, I used L'Hospital on $\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{xf(x)+\sin(3x)}{x^3})$ which yields $\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{xf'(x)+f(x)+3\cos(3x)}{3x^2})=0$, then because the limit of the denominator is zero and the limit exists, it can be shown the limit of the numerator is zero, which yields $f(0)=0$. But then I noticed--this is wrong, isn't it? L'Hospital does not say that if $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=a$, then $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=a$ in fact, the rule states it the other way round.

Well so I was stuck at the first step, but I assume if I were to successfully find $f(0)$, which would most likely be $0$, then I could use the definition of differentiability at x=0: $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$. Then I'm stuck here as well--

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!